# How to add objects to an array and avoid duplicate keys for an object?

Tags: javascript

I have these 2 arrays:

```
productsForSale = ['eggs', 'eggs', 'bread', 'milk'];
soldPrice = [2.70, 2.50, 1.97, 3.29];
```

yes, the values of the first 2 elements ("eggs") are different but that's meant to be for this question. Now I want to create an array of objects that will look like this:

```
[
 {
  eggs: 2.70
 },
 {
  eggs: 2.50
 },
 {
  bread: 1.97
 },
 {
  milk: 3.29
 }     
]
```

So far I have this code:

```
  var obj = {};
  var arr = [];
    productsForSale.forEach((key, i) => {
       obj[key]  = soldPrice[i];
       arr.push(obj);
   });
```

But I don't get the expected output. Can anyone point me in the right dirrection? Thanks

Comment: You should declare the obj inside the forEach function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map().

```js
const productsForSale = ["eggs", "eggs", "bread", "milk"];
const soldPrice = [2.7, 2.5, 1.97, 3.29];

const output = productsForSale.map((el, i) => ({ [el]: soldPrice[i] }));

console.log(output);
```